# PHP Redirecting based on this error

Tags: php, mysql

(Please bear with me.) I want to redirect to a page if this error is produced. If there is a duplicate entry in the database (i.e. If something goes wrong after submission to db but the user resubmits the page.)

> Error: INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp, business_name, business_type, username, main_email, password) VALUES (NOW(), '123', 'Hotel', '123', 'jkljllk@mrmd.com', '$2y$10$gYxXbmHKNmqrEHhB2qOw8uVVs7HNOmdN4oTpv8m98.lN/3R6MwseG') Duplicate entry '123' for key ‘PRIMARY’

My code currently is set on this else:

```
else {
   echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

What I want to do is redirect them to a log in/error page, so they can log in and finish the registration from the admin panel.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

```
 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp,
         business_name,
         business_type,
         username,
         main_email,
         password) 

         VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($business_name, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($business_type, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($main_email, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

        if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username_check;
            $_SESSION['business_name'] = $business_name;
            $_SESSION['business_type'] = $business_type;
            header('Location: ../../register/' .$business_type_link);

        }

        "UPDATE $table_name SET

        business_name='$business_name',
        business_type='$business_type',
        username=$username_entry,
        main_email='$main_email',
        password = '$hashPass'


        WHERE id='$user_id' LIMIT 1");  

        mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: The error is that you have the record in the db then the user edits, submits again and you need to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

```
 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp,
         business_name,
         business_type,
         username,
         main_email,
         password) 

         VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        GetSQLValueString($business_name, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($business_type, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($main_email, "text"), 
        GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"));

$affected += mysqli_rows_affected($link);
$insert_error = mysqli_errorno($link);

        "UPDATE $table_name SET

        business_name='$business_name',
        business_type='$business_type',
        username=$username_entry,
        main_email='$main_email',
        password = '$hashPass'
        WHERE id='$user_id' LIMIT 1");  

$affected += mysqli_rows_affected($link);
$insert_error = mysqli_errorno($link);

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username_check;
            $_SESSION['business_name'] = $business_name;
            $_SESSION['business_type'] = $business_type;

        }
        mysqli_close($link);
```

After the INSERT and UPDATE, then check the data if the is a problem.

And do the users a favor, Do not reject their user name.  Allow duplicate user names.

If you want to use unique user names and force the user to come up with a unique name, add some analytics to see how many abandon your site rather than continue to sign up.

If a unique user name must be used like here on stackoverflow, then have a user name for log in and an on screen name. stackoverflow uses email for log in.

```
if ($affected == 0){

  // do error detection / correction here
  // create warnings

  include('form.php');
  exit

}
else{
  include('next_page.php');
}
```

**end of update**

---

### You do NOT want to Redirect

Use an include, and repopulate the INPUTS.

To eliminate the duplicate you first do the INSERT and immediately follow the INSERT with an UPDATE.

```
INSERT INTO di_ssenisub (timestamp, business_name, business_type, username, main_email, password)
```

No need to check for an error it is faster to just do the update.  It is very quick when the record exists.

```
UPDATE `di_ssenisub` SET `business_name` = '123', `business_type`,...
WHERE `username` = '123';
```

The WHERE term uses the columns in the PRIMARY Index.  The rest go in the SET.

---

If you want to validate the values if you find a problem DO NOT do a Redirect (`header("Location: ')

You want to pass the problems found on to the user.

Let's say you find a problem like invalid email:

$warn_email = '*";

include('form.php');
exit;

In form.php

```
$warn_email<inpupt name="email"
```

---

**Repopulate the INPUTS**

You have the submitted data:

```
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
$business_name = $_POST['business_name'];
$business_type = $_POST['business_type'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$main_email = $_POST['main_email'];
```

With an include these values will automatically be passed to the form.

```
 <input type="text" name="business_name" value="$business_name" />
 <input type="text" name="business_type" value="$business_type" />
 <input type="text" name="username" value="$username" />
 <input type="text" name="main_email" value="$main_email" />
```

If they are going in Fresh, then the variables are empty, and you get `value=""` in your HTML.

---

If you want to check for an INSERT and OR UPDATE error do this:

```
$affected = 0;

INSERT ...

$affected += mysqli_rows_affected($link);

UPDATE ...

$affected += mysqli_rows_affected($link);

if ($affected == 0){echo 'Houston we have a problem';}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you. I dont understand how that solves my problem. Lets say the user tried to register twice. The INSERT would be ignored? And the UPDATE would work?...

Comment: Yes it is better than doing an error check on the Insert.  If there is no error on the insert the UPDATE will do nothing. It would return zero rows affected.

Comment: So (sorry if i seem stupid)  are you saying use an UPDATE as an else{}

Comment: Instead of an else.  The error from the INSERT you just ignore.  The time it takes to do an unnecessary UPDATE if faster than doing `if (insert error) {update}`  So just always do both.

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to know, how to detect the error or how to redirect? If you want to redirect to another page, then the answer by holpducki is correct:

```
header("Location:http://www.example.com/login.php");
exit;
```

If you are trying to detect an error, then you can use either the `mysql_errno()` or `mysql_error()` PHP functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php

For example:

```
if (mysql_errno($resource) == 1092) {
    header("Location:http://www.example.com/login.php");  // send to login
    exit;
} else {
    ...
}
```

List of MySQL error numbers can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

And here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-client.html

Comment: If a redirect is done all is lost.  Using an include preserves all the variables.  FYI: includes should be used instead of redirect to save the Round Trip HTTP requests that the Browser has to do for a redirect.  It can be multiple requests and take seconds..

Comment: I want to redirect based on a duplicate entry on a certain table

Comment: Yeh but the thing is I would link the back to a login page that would explain the error and allow them to login to the admin to continue their registration/profile…..

Comment: That's why the include will work much better.  You can also repopulate the data the user entered.  A redirect will require the user to reenter everything and not know why.

Comment: What is the $resource?

Comment: @Misunderstood: The OP isn't being very clear about what he needs, so, it's a bit difficult to offer the best solution. If he has no idea what a $resource variable is for mysql commands, he should probably just hire a PHP programmer.